# Contour Plots in Groupplot

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I am trying to produce a `groupplot` with two contour plots.  I suspect I could work this out on my own given enough time to play with it, but I am up against a bit of a time crunch...

As background, this `groupplot` is supposed to replace a plot of two surfaces that doesn't present very well in black and white.  Here's the surface

[image]

Each surface represents an algorithm, and the idea is to show that one is insensitive to the alpha parameter, while the other is insensitive to the lambda parameter.

I'd never done a `pgfplots` contour plot before, so I began with the basics. Here's code for one of the contour plots...the data file can be found at http://pastebin.com/TzJJ7KZF

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                \addplot[contour/draw color=black, contour/label distance=100pt,contour prepared, contour prepared format=matlab]
                    table {CAG_Contour.dat};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This produced the following figure
[image]

It's rough I know...lacks axis labels, and for some reason those 14's overlap, but I figured I could puzzle that out.

But when I tried to put two contours together in a `groupplot` I was too far out of my depth.  The code looks like this....the data files can be found at CAG_Contour.dat is at [pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/TzJJ7KZF) and PPR_Contour.dat is at [pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/g1a86UBr)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
                group size=2 by 1,
                xlabels at=edge bottom,
                ylabels at=edge left},
                xlabel = {\footnotesize $\alpha_{++}$},
                ylabel = {\footnotesize Departure Rate}]
            \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Come and Go}]
                \addplot+[contour/draw color=black,contour prepared, contour prepared format=matlab]
                          table {CAG_Contour.dat};
            \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize ++Resources}]
                \addplot+[contour prepared, contour prepared format=matlab]
                          table {PPR_Contour.dat};
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The resulting figure looks like

[image]

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the contour lines to draw

1. in black
2. smaller width

Or how to increase the spacing between the labels

Obviously the `contour/draw color=black` approach isn't correct.

Apologies for such  poorly formed question...Ideally I'm supposed to show this to my committee tomorrow...

Comment: Can you provide some data for testing?

Comment: What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Post it somewhere like pastebin. or post it here in the question itself.

Comment: Never used pastebin...cool stuff.  The lists are pretty long.  I've copied them to pastebin.  CAG_Contour.dat is at http://pastebin.com/TzJJ7KZF and PPR_Contour.dat is at http://pastebin.com/g1a86UBr  If it's helpful, I guess I could now go back and edit the question into an MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are plotting the marks too and since those marks are too close to each other, the line looks thick. For this either remove `+` from `\addplot` or pass the option `no marks` to `\addplot`.  Then the effect of changing colour can be seen.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
                group size=2 by 1,
                xlabels at=edge bottom,
                ylabels at=edge left},
                xlabel = {\footnotesize $\alpha_{++}$},
                ylabel = {\footnotesize Departure Rate}]
            \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Come and Go}]
                \addplot+[no marks,contour/draw color=black,contour prepared, contour prepared format=matlab,contour/every contour label/.append style={every node/.style={black!50,fill=white}}]
                          table[x index=0,y index=1] {CAG_Contour.dat};
            \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize ++Resources}]
                \addplot[contour/draw color=black,contour prepared, contour prepared format=matlab, contour/every contour label/.append style={every node/.style={black!50,fill=white}}]
                          table[x index=0,y index=1] {PPR_Contour.dat};
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To change the colour of labels, I have used

```
contour/every contour label/.append style={every node/.style={black!50,fill=white}}
```

along with

```
contour/draw color=black,
```

You can change the distance between labels by

```
contour/label distance={<dimension>}
```

Comment: I have reduced the number of data points for trial.

Comment: Simply removing the + made an immense difference!  The plot on the right is still ugly as sin because of how non-smooth the contours are, but I can work on that.  If I can't figure it out, it probably warrants a new thread anyway.  Thanks!